# Unable to connect to SMTP server - When creating a tenant

Tags: deepsecurity

When creating a tenant against a system running Deep Security/11.3.184 I'm receiving the following response:

```
{
    "message":"Unable to connect to SMTP server. Please verify the SMTP configuration in System Settings."
}
```

The API resource I'm calling is '/tenants' and the HTTP Method is POST.  The body of the request (with some details anonymised) is:

```
{
    "administrator": {
        "active": true,
        "emailAddress": "******@********.***",
        "fullName": "****** ****",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "password": "*******",
        "primaryContact": true,
        "receiveNotifications": false,
        "roleID": 1,
        "timeFormat": "24",
        "timeZone": "UTC",
        "username": "admin"
    },
    "databaseServerID": 1,
    "description": "1190000206_11174_njkhnjklh",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "modulesVisible": [
        "all"
    ],
    "name": "1190000206_11174_njkhnjklh",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

What reasons are there that this response can happen?  Note I don't manage the DeepSecurity application, I'm asking as a 3rd party, so will need to relay the details on to the team that do manage the DeepSecurity application.

Answer (score 1):

This response happens when there is no configured SMTP service on Deep Security Manager, and the request to create the tenant requires an email confirmation. Your request body looks ok, but you need to add the confirmationRequired query parameter set to false:

```
https://dsm.example.com:4119/api/tenants?confirmationRequired=false
```

If you're using an SDK, this is set in a parameter of the TenantApi.createTenant method (or function), for example in Python:

```
tenants_api.create_tenant(tenant, api_version, confirmation_required=False)
```

An example can be found here:
https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/article/11_3/create-and-manage-tenants#createtenant

Hope that helps. BTW I'm a Deep Security content developer - thanks for your question!